# Dynamically built functions in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, metaprogramming

I have a question concerning dynamically built functions (or something comparable). In Java I can write some Source programmatically into a String, compile this string and execute it like a function several times.

Imagine I have some genetic algorithm to create the best code for taking n input parameters, calculate them according the genome and returning m output parameters. So I wonder if it's possible (and I'm quite sure it is), to create a list of lists of lists .... containing the function, and then call this function some thousand times with different input parameters to calculate the error rate.

What I do need now is an example, how to create such a list programmatically and how to use it. Currently I'm totally stuck.

Any references or examples warmly welcomed.

Comment: Which Lisp are you using? Common Lisp?

Comment: Steel Bank Common Lisp

Comment: Any beginner Lisp book will explain how to do something that. A quick internet search will come up with a zillion examples. You could read a manual. Why not put some of your own effort into a basically trivial question? If you have any problems, show your code and somebody will help you. Stackoverflow isn't really the place to ask questions without any code, any examples, any example applications, any attempts to solve it. Please put some effort into it.

Comment: A single reference would be nice.

Comment: You write 'compile this function for speed'. Why not search for 'compile' & 'function' & 'lisp'? The google result set looks promising...

Comment: Sorry, but did you even understand the main problem? I know how to compile a function. I know how to write a function. But I don't know, how to construct a function by code, not by typing it in.

Comment: (compile 'this-is-a-function '(lambda () "WOW")) - (this-is-a-function) - the COMPILE documentation gives already such an example. You could have read it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lisp code is data: lists, symbols, numbers, ...

```
(defun foo () 42)
```

Lisp has functions like `list` and `+`. You can use it:

```
(list 'defun
      'foo
      '()
      (+ 25 17))
```

How do you compile a function? Eval the code and compile it.

```
(compile (eval my-function-definition))
```

So put together:

```
CL-USER 10 > (compile (eval (list 'defun 'foo '() (+ 25 17))))
FOO
NIL
NIL

CL-USER 11 > (foo)
42
```

Is it really compiled?

```
CL-USER 11 > (disassemble 'foo)
424000EA3C:
       0:      49396275         cmpq  [r10+75], rsp
       4:      7720             ja    L1
       6:      4883F900         cmpq  rcx, 0
      10:      751A             jne   L1
      12:      4157             push  r15
      14:      55               push  rbp
      15:      4889E5           moveq rbp, rsp
      18:      4989DF           moveq r15, rbx
      21:      BF50010000       move  edi, 150
      26:      B901000000       move  ecx, 1
      31:      4889EC           moveq rsp, rbp
      34:      5D               pop   rbp
      35:      415F             pop   r15
      37:      C3               ret   
L1:   38:      41FFA6E7020000   jmp   [r14+2E7]        ; SYSTEM::*%WRONG-NUMBER-OF-ARGUMENTS-STUB
      45:      90               nop   
      46:      90               nop   
      47:      90               nop   
      48:      90               nop   
      49:      90               nop   
      50:      90               nop   
      51:      90               nop
```

Seems so...

Answer (score 3):

As Rainer Joswig said, you should read some Lisp book (particularily the chapters about list manipulation and macros), but here's a very simple example using [`compile`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp.htm):

```
(defun test (op number)
  (let ((func (compile nil `(lambda (y)
                              (,op y y)))))
    (format t "The function is ~:[not compiled~;compiled~].~%"
            (compiled-function-p func))
    (funcall func number)))

(test '+ 5) ; => 10
(test '* 5) ; => 25
```

This constructs the `lambda` expression using [backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) syntax, but you could  just build it with regular list manipulation operations (`push`, `cons` and such) as well.

Comment: I just opened this question in order to write approximately this answer. Good one.